# Code to Fetch information from sql oracle database on premises using API

Tags: sql, oracle, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I am building a chatbot using AWS Lex and Lambda. 
To respond to my user I need to fetch data from an oracle sql server which is on premise and not on cloud. I have been told to use API connecting lambda to the SQL server.

Following are my questions:-

1) Are there any REST APIs on Oracle 11g that could be used for the same? If yes, how do I get the URL to the database and how do I execute SQL queries?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Maheep, try searching for 'oracle rest api' or 'oracle soda' and see what you get.

Comment: Just as an aside, the term 'sql server' is generally used and understood to refer to the RDBMS product from Microsoft.  Therefore, "oracle sql server" is an oxymoron.  It's like saying "i own a Ford Toyota'.  :-)